# node.js version issue or something else

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I have

```
"node":"0.10.12", 
"npm":"1.2.30"
```

in my package and i have installed

```
node 0.10.26
```

and

```
npm 1.4.7
```

and having an

```
error Failed at the Kiwi-Move-API@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the Kiwi-Move-API package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node server.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls Kiwi-Move-API
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-35-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /home/asnadatta/work/kiwi/kiwi-devkit
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

this is my complete package

```
{
  "name": "Kiwi-Move-API",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Kiwi Move Webservices API",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node":"0.10.12",
    "npm":"1.2.30"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.3.4",
    "mongoose": "~3.6.14",
    "mongo": "~0.1.0",
    "redis": "~0.8.4",
    "ws": "~0.4.27",
    "mocha": "~1.12.0",
    "bcrypt": "0.7.6",
    "node-oauth2-server":"1.5.0",
    "underscore":"1.5.1",
    "nodemailer":"0.5.2", 
    "should":"1.2.2",
    "request":"2.25.0",
    "nano": "~4.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Kiwi",
    "Move",
    "Kiwi",
    "Wearable",
    "Tech"
  ],
  "author": "Mike Holmes",
  "license": "BSD"
}
```

Is this versions issue or some thing else

Comment: What is your complete package.json ?

Comment: does server.js exists ?

Comment: if you run "node server.js" what happens?

Comment: npm start but I also tried node server.js

Comment: Then error is changed to invalid ELF header

Comment: I have also tested it with app.js and get same result